# Trigger Button with Key instead of Mouse Click

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks for any help with this. Basically I have a stop button on a timer - and I need to have it be activated via a key press instead of or in addition to being able to click it with mouse. I've tried a few different ways using document.addeventlistener for example but nothing I have done has worked. Below is the relevant HTML/JS. Can anyone point me in the right direction of how I should best go about this? For example ideally I will press a number on the num pad to stop my counter. I'm not sure how to separate the two lines of code in the block format wise below, but just know button is in its proper html tags and the stop button is within script tags.

Thank you

```
<button id="stop" class="btn btn-danger">STOP</button>


    /* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clear = true;
    start.disabled = false;
    stop.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: You can use keydown/keyup event for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event

Comment: What about <button onclick="stopFunc()" ... And id may not work so simply - you should use document.all.id (IE only) or document.getElementById('stop')

Answer (score 0):

Here, I created an example for the keydown event. Use tab key navigate to stop button and then press enter key it will get disabled.

```js
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("keypress", stopTimer, false); 
function stopTimer() {
    document.getElementById("stop").setAttribute('disabled', true);
}
```

```html
<button id="stop">STOP</button>
```

Comment: thanks but this only seems to disable the button not actually stop the timer as well - going to try using the link you posted

Comment: You need to add an example of what is the required.

Answer (score 0):

For the button element, click event has triggered on both, click and keypress as you can see below (this happen when you press spacebar or return, with another key just trigger keypress event); but on anyway you can set more than one event on your element.

```js
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click",function(){
  console.log('Clicked!');
});

document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("keypress",function(){
  console.log('Keypressed!');
});
```

```html
<button id="stop">Stop!</button>
```

if you need no-mouse interaction, you have to focus the element...

```js
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click",function(){
  console.log('Clicked!');
});

document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("keypress",function(){
  console.log('Keypressed!');
});

document.getElementById("stop").focus();
```

```html
<button id="stop">Stop!</button>
```